# SAS - today() in a proc freq where clause

Tags: sas

I'm using SAS and trying to automatically pick up today's date and put it into the where clause for a proc freq.

it looks likes this:

```
proc freq data=data_name;
  tables date_col;
  where date_col > '30aug2017'd;
run;
```

Instead of 30aug2017 i want today() but i'm struggling to get this working, i 've tried:

```
data create_date;
current1 = today();
format current1 date9.;
run;

proc freq data=data_name;
  tables date_col;
  where date_col > current1;
run;
```

but the error i get is that variable is not on file

Any help appreciated,

cheers guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TODAY() directly in your WHERE statement.

```
 where date_col > today();
```

Comment: i tried that before and thought it didn't work. Just realised it's because the data isn't available for today....

Comment: I'd recommend using `%sysfunc(today())` to avoid the function firing on every record

Comment: Very commonly I use period of x days like this: date_col > date() - 20, where x is 20 in this case.